# How to display 2 values in a textbox?

Tags: c#, random, textbox, display

I am trying to display two random generated numbers in a text-box using visual studio.

This is what I have so far...

```
int RandomNumber(int min = 0, int max = 100)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                return random.Next(min, max);
            }
            int RandomNumber2(int min = 0, int max = 100)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                return random.Next(min, max);
            }
            txtQuestion.Enabled = true;

        string num1 = Convert.ToString(RandomNumber());
        string num2 = Convert.ToString(RandomNumber2());

        txtQuestion.Text = ("{0} + {1} = ?", num1, num2);
```

However, the last line comes up with the error " cannot implicitly convert type '(string, string num1, string num2)' to 'string' "

How am I supposed to output these randomly generated numbers in the textbox?

Hi below is the edited code that works to how I needed it. Thanks for all the help :)

```
Random random1 = new Random();
```

I called the above function globally so I can refer to it every time I need a new random number. And below is how I used it in my function to call for two different random numbers and display them in a text-box.

```
            int randomNumber1 = random1.Next(0, 10);
        int randomNumber2 = random1.Next(0, 10);

        string num1 = Convert.ToString(randomNumber1);
        string num2 = Convert.ToString(randomNumber2);

        txtQuestion.Text = string.Format ("{0} + {1} = ?", num1, num2);
```

Comment: You appear to be missing `string.Format`. At the moment it looks like you're creating a `ValueTuple` of (string, string, string).

Comment: You also do not need a `new` random object each time.  A single one can generate an infinite number of random values for the life of the program.

Comment: You don’t write a new method every time you want to call it. That’s one of the fundamental points of methods.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp How should I implement this in my code?

Comment: @randomdude Just call `random.Next(min, max)` each time you need a random number. That's why it's called `Next` and not `Result` or something.

Answer (score 2):

As @John said, you are using a ValueTuple.
You can learn more about ValueTuple [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/valuetuple) or on the msdn. But the link I gave shows almost the same code as you wrote.

What you want to do is either to use string.Format :

```
txtQuestion.Text = string.Format("{0} + {1} = ?", num1, num2);
```

Or more concise with string interpolation :

```
txtQuestion.Text = $"{num1} + {num2} = ?";
```

And show the answer like this :

```
Random random = new Random();
int nextRandom() => random.Next(0, 100);
int num1 = nextRandom();
int num2 = nextRandom();
txtQuestion.Text = $"{num1} + {num2} = {num1 + num2}";
// If you have a method that computes the result you can also call it inside
txtQuestion.Text = $"{num1} + {num2} = {SomeFunction(num1, num2)}";
```

To fix your random issue, you must create a random instance only once.

```
class MyClass
{
    // Use the same instance of Random.
    private Random _random = new Random();

    public int RandomNumber()
    {
        return _random.Next(0, 100);
    }

    public void DisplayText()
    {
        int num1 = RandomNumber();
        int num2 = RandomNumber();
        txtQuestion.Text = $"{num1} + {num2} = {num1 + num2}";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great it displays the random numbers, however, both random values are the same.

Comment: Give me 2 min to edit my answer to show you the problem